# What is the equivalent of "Alt+Insert" in IntelliJ for Citrix Windows from Mac Keyboard?

Tags: windows, macos, intellij-idea, citrix

I have a mac keyboard connecting to a citrix workspace which has windows based intellij. When I do Option + Enter it takes me to a new line rather than doing the import or any correction which Alt + Enter option does in Intellij.

Comment: Please check assigned shortcut for "Show Context Action" under "Settings / Preferences (on macOS) | Keymap"

Answer (score 2):

option + command + return should do the trick. Normally Alt is mapped to option + command

Comment: This triggers "Show Context Actions", Any ideas how to trigger "Generate.." which is mapped to Alt + Insert?

Comment: Normally the Citrix Windows comes with an App called "On-Screen Keyboard" that lets you click on a virtual keyboard onscreen. If you're using a Mac keyboard with no Insert key it is one of the options. 
Other is to remap your shortcut to something else than Insert.